# Route not changed on click of back button in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I made 3 routes in my angular2 app i.e " ","login","signup"
. when i directly go to these routes then it works properly, But my browser history doesn't work properly in the following scenario

Suppose i am at home page and navigate to **login** by clicking on login button and then navigate to **signup** by clicking on signup button present on login page.

Now, if i press back button of browser window the it loads the login page but doesn't change the url in browser and it remains static as **abc.com/signup** and when i again press the back button then it loads the signup page but url gets changed to  **abc.com/login** and now the login url represents signup page and signup url represents login page unless i reload the app, which highly ambiguous.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I have followed angular2.1 docs only, nothing different in code.

Comment: The problem is in your code. If you don't show the code we can't help you. "have followed angular2.1 docs" is useless.

Comment: it was working properly until i migrated my app to angular2.1

Comment: yeah, my mistake.. wait let me shorten it out for posting here.